# Unable to do Replication of MySQL DB, Is their any other way to keep online DB updated

Tags: mysql, replication

I am unable to do Replication of local MySQL DB to online DB, Is their any other way to keep online DB updated. Like am I able to create a log file and implement that log file to online mysql DB.

Comment: There are [many ways to do replication in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html), you must mean you can't do a certain *type* of replication. Which one? And what's keeping you from doing it? Does your online DB need to be read-write or read-only? Do writes to the online DB have to be replicated back to the local?

Comment: My online DB do not allow to change my.ini. I tried Workbench. right now I need one way replication from local to online, but in future I need both ways.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would contact your hosting provider to see if they have a solution.  They may be able to set it up for you.

If you have no control over the slave's (read-only online DB) configuration then you *may* be able to do log based replication.  Follow the instructions in [Setting Up Binary Log File Position Based Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html), it should only require issuing SQL commands.

As for replicating both ways (aka master-master or cluster replication) [it's complicated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html). I don't think that's possible without being able to fully control all the servers.

Consider switching to a hosting provider which supports MySQL replication, for example, [Rackspace](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-master-master-replication/).